# mysql_fetch_row returns Array9 when I only want the value 9

Tags: mysql

Im trying to just get the count value using mysql_fetch_row but the echo is Array9, when I just want 9.

```
            <?php
          $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product_category` ORDER BY `product_category_name`");
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

              echo '
              <li  class="ui-shadow" data-count-theme="d">
              <a href="' . $row['product_category_ref_page'] . '.php" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">' . $row['product_category_name'] . '</a><span class="ui-li-count">' . 

                $number = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`category_id`) FROM `products_has_product_category` WHERE `category_id`=" . $row['product_category_id'] . ""));
                echo $number[0];

              '</span></li>';
          }

        ?>
```

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: this is not entire code.

Comment: @Dev I reposted the entire code, I did not think it would affect the specific part I was looking to correct.  I appreciate any suggestions you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a nested query. Can be done with a JOIN, something like as follows:-

```
    SELECT a.*, COUNT(b.category_id) AS CatCount
    FROM `product_category` a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `products_has_product_category` b
    ON a.product_category_id = b.category_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.someothercolumn, a.etc
```

Comment: This is definitely what I was looking for but the CatCount returns the total number of products not the total of how many products are in each category.

Comment: You need to add a group by clause, containing the column names from a that you are bringing back

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to post my solution that was given by Michael Berkowski on another post, I hope it will help someone else!  And thanks to Kickstart for pointing my in the right direction!

```
<?php
          $result = mysql_query("
                        SELECT
                        a.product_category_id, a.product_category_name, a.product_category_ref_page,
                        catcount
                        FROM
                        product_category a
                        LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT category_id, COUNT(*)  AS catcount
                        FROM products_has_product_category 
                        GROUP BY category_id
                        ) subcount ON a.product_category_id = subcount.category_id
                    ");
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

              echo '
              <li  class="ui-shadow" data-count-theme="d">
              <a href="' . $row['product_category_ref_page'] . '.php" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">' . $row['product_category_name'] . '</a><span class="ui-li-count">' . $row['catcount'] . '</span></li>';
          }

        ?>
```